# Welche Bedeutung haben die Farben in dieser Karte?

Tags: gender

Welche Bedeutung haben die Farbe in dieser Weltkarte? Es ist eine sprachliche Bedeutung.

[image]

Comment: @c.p. UK ist verbuggt... http://i.stack.imgur.com/Vegn1.png

Comment: Das Land, das England enthält, ist nicht verbuggt. Es ist gelb/grau geteilt.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is a riddle asked in the style of puzzling.stackexchange.com. It is off-topic there because it is in German, but it is similarly off-topic here, because **it has nothing to do with understanding the German language.** As such, it should be closed and removed imho.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rot dargestellt sind die Länder,

> die im Deutschen Maskulinum sind: der Sudan, der Jemen, der Iran...

Dunkelblau dargestellt sind die Länder,

> die im Deutschen Femininum sind: die Schweiz, die Türkei, die Ukraine, die Mongolei...

Gelb dargestellt die die Länder,

> die im Deutschen Neutrum sind: das Vereinigte Königreich...

Hellblau dargestellt sind die Länder,

> die im Deutschen Plural sind: die USA/Vereinigten Staaten, die Philippinen, die Niederlande...

---

**Spoiler in den Kommentaren**

Comment: Die meisten werden ohne Artikel gebraucht. Man sagt üblicherweise nicht "das Deutschland" oder "das Frankreich" (wobei es da Ausnahmen gibt, z.b. "das Frankreich des 18. Jahrhunderts"), sondern "Deutschland" und "Frankreich".