# Präposition für fliegen

Tags: preposition

Ich weiß, dass dieser Satz richtig ist:

> Im Sommer fliege ich in die USA.

Kann ich auch sagen:

> Im Sommer fliege ich nach den USA.

Gibt es andere Präpositionen, die ich benutzen kann?

Comment: Related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/12078/welche-bedeutung-haben-die-farben-in-dieser-karte

Comment: Related: [Using “nach” or “zu” for landmarks and similar](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/17671/using-nach-or-zu-for-landmarks-and-similar)

Comment: Related: [Richtungen und Ziele: Wir fahren “nach / in / zu / an” Artikel XYZ](http://german.stackexchange.com/a/8483/44)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Could be related to the gender

- **fliegen nach** for countries without an article or some neuter country names

  > Im Sommer fliege ich **nach** Kanada / Mexiko / Venezuela / Frankreich / Deutschland / China (neuter)
- **fliegen in** for masculine / feminine / plural countries used with an article

  > Im Sommer fliege ich **in** den Jemen / Sudan  (masculine)
  >   Im Sommer fliege ich **in** die Türkei / Schweiz / Ukraine / Niederlande (feminine)
  >   Im Sommer fliege ich **in** die Vereinigten Arabischen Emirate / Staaten (USA)  (plural)

Comment: Almost: You'd also say "Ich fliege ins Vereinigte Königreich", which is neuter. You use "nach" for countries that are used without an article in German.

Comment: @elena Interesting. I'll keep it in mind.

Answer (score 2):

Nein, aber das hat mit `fliegen` an sich nichts zu tun. Richtig wäre:

> Ich fliege nach Kuba, nach Mallorca, nach China, nach Neuseeland, nach Indien.

"... nach USA" klingt für mich falsch, hört man aber immer wieder.

Natürlich kann man auch durch, über, unter, neben, zwischen usw. fliegen.

Answer (score 1):

Die USA heißen übersetzt "Vereinigte Staaten von Amerika".

Im Deutschen wird oftmals die Präposition anhand dieser deutschen Entsprechung gewählt.
Da man sich auf „die Staaten“ bezieht, wird "in" genutzt.

> "Ich fliege nach Amerika"

ist richtig und das hört man auch oft.

Ansonsten benutzt man für gewöhnlich "nach" als Präposition für Länder in die eine Reise angetreten wird.