# Fliegen von/aus den USA

Tags: preposition

Man sagt:

> [Ich fliege in die USA.](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/12384/pr%C3%A4position-f%C3%BCr-fliegen)

Sagt man

> Ich fliege morgen **aus** den USA in die Niederlande.

oder

> Ich fliege morgen **von** den USA in die Niederlande.

oder anderes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es gibt zwei Paare **aus–in** und **von–nach**. Das *aus–in*-Paar muss man dann verwenden, wenn nach *in* ein bestimmter Artikel folgt. Also z.B. mit *in die Niederlande*. Sonst braucht man *von-nach*.

> Er nahm den Flug aus Deutschland in die USA.
>
> Er nahm den Flug von Berlin nach München.

Die Paare zu mischen ist nicht falsch, klingt aber etwas seltsam:

> Er nahm den Flug von Deutschland in die USA.
>
> Er nahm den Flug aus Deutschland nach Puerto Rico.

In beiden Fällen ist der Abflugort Deutschland durch den "nicht passenden" Partner besonders betont.