# Warum 'in die Türkei' aber 'nach Italien'?

Tags: grammatical-case

Warum heißt es

> Ich fahre **in** die Türkei in den Urlaub.

aber bei anderen Ländern

> Ich fahre **nach** Italien in den Urlaub.

Comment: Also see: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/12078/welche-bedeutung-haben-die-farben-in-dieser-karte